# Syncing a folder on two PC connected to the same router

Tags: windows-10, permissions, sync, lan, shared-folders

I have two PCs running on Windows 10. I have been using `\\PC01` but now `\\PC02` is joining. There is a folder `\\PC01\Users\Matthew\Documents\folderToShare` and I want it to synchronize with `\\PC02\Users\Matthew\Documents\folderToShare`. By synchronize I mean

- Each of `\\PC01` and `\\PC02` keeps its local copy of the folder and its content
- Whenever both PCs are turned on, the two folders and their contents sync in real-time

Is it possible to achieve this with Windows 10 utilities? I am not keen on installing 3rd-party app...

---

As a side note, I am actually still at the stage of experimenting with folder sharing (i.e. only one physical copy in `\\PC01` and without sync function, but `\\PC02` can access `\\PC01\Users\Matthew\Documents\folderToShare`) but I even fail at this simple stage!

I mean, I can see the both `\\PC01` and `\\PC02` in the File Explorer on `\\PC02`, like this:

[image]

However, when I try to update the permission on `\\PC01` to allow `\\PC02` to access that folder, `\\PC02` is not there for me to choose, like this:

[image]

---

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Assuming both computers have the same Microsoft Account, you can put the data in the Public Folder area of the users account and share these. That works.
2. Assuming nothing:  Pick one computer as the main sharing computer, put the data in a neutral folder (not Users) and then the other computer can use Users.  Set up traditional folder sharing and the two computers can share files.

I do that here and it works. For true synchronization, I prefer and use Sync Back Pro.

> two folders and their contents sync in real-time

Real time can be a bit difficult. Sync Back Pro can be run to a schedule - say hourly or whatever and that suffices for most things.  I sync two or three times daily and never lost anything of any significance.

Remember that you must share out the folder on the main computer to the other computer.

It may make things easier to put the user name and password of PC2 on PC1 using Users and Groups on PC1.